# Displaying a WPF popup from a thread in an office add-in

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, vsto

I'm trying to display a WPF Popup that will indicate some progress:

The problem is that the popup is not displayed before the Thread.Sleep completes, this is only an example, in my program I have complex IO and DB logic that needs to be executed synchronously and the progress needs to be displayed on the popup.

Here is my example code:

```
    private ProgressBar m_ProgressBar;

    private void buttonDoWork_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var progressPopup = new Popup { PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Fade, StaysOpen = true, Height = 150, Width = 260 };
        m_ProgressBar = new ProgressBar
                              {
                                  HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                                  VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
                              };

        progressPopup.Child = m_ProgressBar;

        progressPopup.IsOpen = true;

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        this.m_ProgressBar.Value = 25;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        this.m_ProgressBar.Value = 50;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        this.m_ProgressBar.Value = 75;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        this.m_ProgressBar.Value = 100;
    }
```

**Update**

The problem is that the logic which blocks the main thread needs to stay on the main thread, there is nothing else I can do. Is there a way to run the popup on a separate thread?

Comment: If you need progress reports, why wouldn't you use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)? In a regular thread/task, you'd have to use a [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) class to manipulate the elements in UI thread.

Comment: Because I need to display buttons and other UI controls in that popup too.

Comment: Well, the BackgroundWorker's `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` event methods run in UI thread, only the `DoWork` method runs in a different thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
Dispather.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{ this.m_ProgressBar.Value = progress; });
```

to update the progress bar on the UI thread.

In general you shouldn't weave your code like this (UI and logic mixed up)

You could use the BackgroundWorker or a Task that reports progress by raising an event.

**EDIT**

To clarify: expose the data that changes from your ViewModel/code and raise events (PropertyChanged) so you can bind the UI to those values. That will allow you to keep UI and code separated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `BackgroundWorker` where the split of the UI thread and the background thread is very clear.

Using it for example you can sign to the `ProgressChanged` event (that belongs to the UI thread) and do whatever you want to inform the user about your background process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that WPF requires that the message loop be spinning so that it can dispatch the messages for showing, painting, responding to events, etc. You have to structure your code so that `buttonDoWork_Click` exits as soon as possible. If you do not then the whole UI will freeze.

Furthermore, incrementing the progress value inside that single method basically does nothing. From the perspective of the of the message loop the progress value contained only a single value...100. That is the last value you wrote to the `ProgressBar` before the click event ended. That is the only value the progress bar knows about when it is finally allowed to refresh itself.

You need to get that long running operation off the UI thread. Here is what I advise.

- Use the `Task` class start your operation on a worker thread.
- Have your worker thread publish the progress information to a simple variable.
- Have your UI thread poll for the progress information via a timer on an interval you choose. Update the `ProgressBar` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but there must be some other way, maybe it's possible to loop through the messages on a separate thread?

Comment: @anima: No, UI elements have thread affinity. That means that they are bound permantently to the UI thread. Any attempt to access them or manipulate the message queue from another thread will go wrong. This really is the best way. Put the long running operation on a worker thread and keep the UI stuff on the UI thread.